# Recursion = scary! (Codeigniter PHP)

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter, recursion, static-members

I've always hated recursion because my mind cannot cope with infinite loops and I can't find a way to think about it properly. I'm trying to figure out how to print an array of values using it. I want to compile the result into a string and return it and use `&nbsp;` to space it properly:

```
  var $count=0;
  static $formatted='';
  function Process_Array($array) 
  {   
    global $count,$formatted;

    $count++; //this variable is for calculating tab space

    if(is_array($array) === true)
    {   
      foreach($array as $key => $value)
      {
      echo "<br /><br />Value=";print_r($value);

        if(is_array($value) === true)
        {
          $this->Process_Array($value);
        }
        else 
        {
          //Calculate tab spacing (level in tree).
          for($i = 1 ; $i < $count ; $i++)
            $formatted.="&nbsp;&nbsp;";

          $formatted.=$value."<br />";
        }
      }
    }   
    $count--;
    $final=$formatted;
    $formatted='';
    return $final;
  }
```

I've tried reading numerous articles but this just gets me. This was some code I downloaded and modified.

Comment: Share an example of your input and desired output.

Comment: recursion (n). 1. see recursion.

Comment: Side note: you know that `globals` are bad right? BTW what version of PHP are you using?

Comment: Here is a link to the method which is used to generate the array: http://pastebin.com/Zsv4XDgD

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9280434/recursion-scary-codeigniter-php

Comment: Why do you want to use recursion?

Comment: $this->Process_Array($value); is an odd line.  1) it does not look like Process_Array is actually part of a class. If it is not, why are you calling $this?  2) In a recursive function after returning a value the value is typically stored, however you are ignoring the return value of Process_Array within the function.

Comment: Thanks for these solutions, I'll have a look at them and see if I can get the logic right.

Comment: Matthieu: I want to use recursion because I have a potentially unlimited tree of projects and subprojects. So it seemed like the only way of doing it. PeeHaa: I don't know why globals would be bad.

Answer (score 1):

One of the interesting things about functional languages (Haskell, OCaml) as opposed to {} languages, is that you don't get loops. Iteration is accomplished with recursion. So it seems funny to me to have foreach loops in a recursive function. Why not just use loops for everything?

Recursion requires a base case, and a recursive step. If you are printing out an array, a good base case might be to check if the array is empty, and return. The recursive step would then pop off the first element and print it out.

```
function printArray($array)
{
    //base case
    if(empty($array)) {
        return;
    }

    print_r(array_pop($array));

    //recursive step
    return printArray($array);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This isn't a complete function for you, but it does add space formatting in the output of an array to denote the depth achieved for elements in a multi-dimensional array without using any global variables.

Hopefully this will help you refine your own solution.

*Updated to reflect returning the output as a string instead of echoing out from the function*

```
function Process_Array($arr, $depth) {
    $retVal = '';
    foreach($arr as $k => $v) {
        for($i = 0; $i < $depth; $i++) 
            $retVal .= '&nbsp;&nbsp;'; 
        $retVal .= $k . ': ';

        if(is_array($v)) 
            $retVal .= '<br>' . Process_Array($v, $depth + 1);
        else
            $retVal .= $v . '<br>';
    }

    return $retVal;
}

$test = array( 
    'test1', 
    'test2', 
    array( 
        'test3', 
        array( 
            'test4', 
            'test5' 
        ), 
        'test6' 
    ), 
    'test7' 
);

echo Process_Array($test, 0);
```

Output:

```
0: test1
1: test2
2:
  0: test3
  1:
    0: test4
    1: test5
  2: test6
3: test7
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another one. I would use additional conditions for objects, though.

```
$arr = array(1,array('2a','2b',array('3a','3b')),4,5,array(),'example','');

function Process_Array($arr, $pre_str='', $space_count=-1) {
    $result = '';
    $spaces = '';
    for ($i = 0; $i < $space_count; $i++) $spaces .= '&nbsp;';
    if (is_array($arr) && !empty($arr)) {
        foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
            $result .= Process_Array($value,$pre_str,$space_count+1);
        }
    } else $result .= $spaces . $pre_str . (empty($arr) ? '' : $arr) . "<br />\n";
    return $result;
}

echo Process_Array($arr,'Value = ');
```

Outputs:

> Value = 1
>   Value = 2a
>   Value = 2b
>     Value = 3a
>    Value = 3b
>  Value = 4
>    Value = 5
>  Value = 
>  Value = example
>  Value =